# Texture Local Rotation but Global Scale

Tags: texturing, texture-coordinates

i try to make a procedural texture for brushed metal, i can use for multiply objects.
Can i somehow achieve that the rotation of the object affects the rotation of the texture, but the scale or size of the object should not affect the scale of the texture.

With texture coordinates -> generated i can lock the rotation of the texture to the object, but if i have a bigger object, then the texture gets scaled up.

If i use texture coordinates -> object and select a empty for scale, the size of the texture stays the same on every object, but the rotation too. So my linear brushed metal is on some objects diagonal instead of horizontal or vertical.

Someone an idea?

thanks!